# Property being changed in CurrentItemChanged event

Tags: c#, data-binding

Is it possible to find out what property is changing while handling the CurrentItemChange event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. BindingManagerBase listens to the ListChanged event from your data source, if the source supports IBindingList. When it gets this event and the ListChangedType property is ItemAdded or ItemChanged and the item position is the same as the current position, it fires the CurrentItemChange event.

So, you have to do the same.